# How to use "for/in" to find components inside of another component?

Tags: delphi

I'm refactoring a component code, and I found the follow code:

```
procedure TMenuToolbarButton.ClearActivation;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Self.Parent.ComponentCount -1 do
  begin
    if (Self.Parent.Components[i] is TMenuToolbarButton) then
    begin
      (Self.Parent.Components[i] as TMenuToolbarButton).FActivatedImage.Visible := False;
      (Self.Parent.Components[i] as TMenuToolbarButton).FActivatedImageGrowLeft.Visible := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I'ts working perfectly today, but i want to use for/in in this method, something like this:

```
procedure TMenuToolbarButton.ClearActivation;
var
  MyMenuToolbarButton: TMenuToolbarButton;
begin
  for MyMenuToolbarButton in Self.Parent do
  begin
    MyMenuToolbarButton.FActivatedImage.Visible         := False;
    MyMenuToolbarButton.FActivatedImageGrowLeft.Visible := False;
  end;
end;
```

I already tried with Generics.Collections casting the `Self.Parent` like this: `TObjectList<TMenuToolbarButton>(Self.Parent)`

So, I want to know if is there a better way to make the working code more "elegant"

Comment: Well, the `for i := 0 to Self.Parent.ComponentCount -1 do` at least has the advantage of being self-documenting, which `for ... in` isn't.  And your `for .. in` doesn't seem to be accessing a collection ,,,

Comment: @MartynA "*And your `for .. in` doesn't seem to be accessing a collection*" - actually, it is. `TComponent` is an iterable collection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  So?  My point was that `Self.Parent` is opaque and the exact opposite of self-documenting.  And I think your answer proves my point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Parent` is a `TWinControl`, not a `TObjectList`, so your attempted typecast is invalid.

You can't use a `for.. in` loop with the `Components` property directly, as it is not an iterable container that meets any of the [documented requirements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#For_Statements):

> Delphi supports `for-element-in-collection` style iteration over containers. **The following container iteration patterns are recognized by the compiler**:
>
> - for Element in ArrayExpr do Stmt;
> - for Element in StringExpr do Stmt;
> - for Element in SetExpr do Stmt;
> - for Element in CollectionExpr do Stmt;
> - for Element in Record do Stmt;

The `Components` property is not an Array, a String, a Set, a Collection, or a Record, so it can't be iterated by a `for..in` loop.

However, `TComponent` itself satisfies the documented requirements of an iterable Collection:

> To use the `for-in` loop construct on a class or interface, the class or interface must implement a prescribed collection pattern. A type that implements the collection pattern must have the following attributes:
>
> - The class or interface must contain a public instance method called `GetEnumerator()`. The `GetEnumerator()` method must return a class, interface, or record type.
> - The class, interface, or record returned by `GetEnumerator()` must contain a public instance method called `MoveNext()`. The `MoveNext()` method must return a `Boolean`. The `for-in` loop calls this method first to ensure that the container is not empty.
> - The class, interface, or record returned by `GetEnumerator()` must contain a public instance, read-only property called `Current`. The type of the `Current` property must be the type contained in the collection.

`TComponent` has a public [`GetEnumerator()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.GetEnumerator) method which returns a [`TComponentEnumerator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponentEnumerator) object that internally iterates the `Components` property. But, since the property deals with `TComponent` objects, you will still have to manually typecast them inside the loop.

Try this:

```pascal
procedure TMenuToolbarButton.ClearActivation;
var
  //i: Integer;
  Comp: TComponent;
  Btn: TMenuToolbarButton;
begin
  //for i := 0 to Self.Parent.ComponentCount -1 do
  for Comp in Self.Parent do
  begin
    //Comp := Self.Parent.Components[i];
    if Comp is TMenuToolbarButton then
    begin
      Btn := TMenuToolbarButton(Comp);
      Btn.FActivatedImage.Visible := False;
      Btn.FActivatedImageGrowLeft.Visible := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

So, using a `for..in` loop does not really gain you anything useful over a traditional `for..to` loop in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

`TComponent` implements method `GetEnumerator` by returning instance of [`TComponentEnumerator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TComponentEnumerator), which enumerates all components owned by this component. In order to use this enumerator you could change your local variable declaration to `var MyMenuToolbarButton: TComponent;`, but you would still need to type-cast inside the loop.

If you really, really want to use `for..in` loop for enumerating components of specified type, you can write your own generic enumerator:

```
type
  TComponentEnumerator<T: TComponent> = record
  private
    FIndex: Integer;
    FComponent: TComponent;
  public
    constructor Create(AComponent: TComponent);
    function GetCurrent: T; inline;
    function GetEnumerator: TComponentEnumerator<T>;
    function MoveNext: Boolean;
    property Current: T read GetCurrent;
  end;

constructor TComponentEnumerator<T>.Create(AComponent: TComponent);
begin
  FIndex := -1;
  FComponent := AComponent;
end;

function TComponentEnumerator<T>.GetCurrent: T;
begin
  Result := T(FComponent.Components[FIndex]);
end;

function TComponentEnumerator<T>.GetEnumerator: TComponentEnumerator<T>;
begin
  Result := Self;
end;

function TComponentEnumerator<T>.MoveNext: Boolean;
begin
  Inc(FIndex);
  while (FIndex < FComponent.ComponentCount) and (not (FComponent.Components[FIndex] is T)) do
    Inc(FIndex);
  Result := FIndex < FComponent.ComponentCount;
end;
```

Usage:

```
procedure TMenuToolbarButton.ClearActivation;
var
  MyMenuToolbarButton: TMenuToolbarButton;
begin
  for MyMenuToolbarButton in TComponentEnumerator<TMenuToolbarButton>.Create(Self.Parent) do
  begin
    MyMenuToolbarButton.FActivatedImage.Visible         := False;
    MyMenuToolbarButton.FActivatedImageGrowLeft.Visible := False;
  end;
end;
```

Few notes:

1. This is pretty naïve implementation which is not protected against some edge cases like changing the components collection while iterating, cross-thread access, ... Of course your original code does none of that, but when you write general purpose class, you should consider making it more foolproof or document its limitations.
2. This implementation enumerates components of type `T` or its descendants.
3. Using enumerators adds [small overhead](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2007/10/more-fun-with-enumerators.html) when compared to simple `for..to` loop.